# How can I share a CSS subclass without repeating myself

Tags: css, sass

I have two different CSS classes which should both use an identical subclass, like this:

```
.front {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  .instructions {
    position:absolute;
    etc.
  }
 }

.back {
  padding: 5%;
  etc.;

  .instructions {
    position:absolute;
    etc.
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in a DRY way? One solution would be to make `.instructions` a top level selector on its own, but I'd like to keep the notion of hierarchy here.  Thanks!

Comment: looks like extend/inheritance at http://sass-lang.com/guide might be what you're looking for.

Comment: As a side note, a lot of people say that changing the style of a class when the container changes is bad practice. I don't fully agree with this; just wanted to make you know.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use [mixin](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6)?

> A mixin lets you make groups of CSS declarations that you want to reuse throughout your site.
>   http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6

**define a mixin**

```
@mixin instructions {
    position:absolute;
    etc.
}
```

**and use it**

```
.front {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  .instructions {
    @include instructions;
  }
 }

.back {
  padding: 5%;
  etc.;

  .instructions {
    @include instructions;
  }
}
```

also you can move `.instructions` into mixin:

```
@mixin instructions {
    .instructions {
        position:absolute;
        etc.
    }
}
.front {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  @include instructions;
 }

.back {
  padding: 5%;
  etc.;
  @include instructions;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of a `@mixin`, which looks too complex for this job, you can use [`@extend`](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7)

> This is one of the most useful features of Sass. Using @extend lets
>   you share a set of CSS properties from one selector to another. **It
>   helps keep your Sass very DRY.**

- The emphasis is mine about the DRY, given that's what you are asking about

something like this:

```css
.instructions {
    position:absolute;
 }

.front {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  @extend .instructions

 }

.back {
  padding: 5%;
  @extend .instructions
}
```

which compiles into this:

```css
.instructions, .front, .back {
  position: absolute;
}

.front {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.back {
  padding: 5%;
}
```

you can see a demo [here](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/7b92b4ef16ecd9a61beb1afc07907359)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
    .front {
      display:flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
     }

    .back {
      padding: 5%;
      etc.;
    }

    .back, .front {
      .instructions {
        position:absolute;
        etc.
      }
    }
```